How do I user Prettier on Laravel Blade?
Quick question, how do I use Prettier to prettify the PHP file with HTML source code in it?
So, here's my index.blade.php file
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>
    
    
        Hello, world!
    </title>
            </head>

</html>

And here's my settings.json configuration
  "prettier.requireConfig": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[php]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },

How do I apply the Prettier HTML in PHP Laravel Blade too?
Thank you!

if you are using vs code, it is better to use laravel blade formatter extension for formatting.
